# Asset Bundles from unity 4 in unity 5 ios build

Tags: unity-game-engine, assetbundle

I am upgrading my app from unity 4 to unity 5, and was using asset bundles. 
I have a PC build and an iOS build of my app. I noticed that on PC the bundles work fine, but on iOS, they cannot be opened. 
I am testing this with a free version of unity 5.

Is it possible to continue using the same asset bundles or do i need to create new ones with unity 5?

*Will i be able to open the bundles on iOS with a pro version?

Answer (score 0):

From Unity's support:

Unity 5 does not support Unity 4.x asset bundles. The asset bundles have to be created again with Unity 5. If Unity 5 somehow does manage to open a Unity 4.x asset bundle, it is just a lucky coincidence, and will break sometime, somewhere.